# How to get all columns in one column with panda dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

Hello I am trying to transpose a table in dataframe as follow, where A and B are both companies name.

This is the dataframe I have so far

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Date         |         A        |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_1         |         34       |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_2         |                  |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_3         |         6        |         321      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

and this is what I am looking to achieve:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Date         |     Company      |      Value       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_1         |         A        |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_1         |         B        |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_2         |         B        |        12        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_3         |         A        |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      date_3         |         B        |        321       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for melt, which should give you what you want.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'],value_vars=['A','B'], var_name='Company',value_name='Value').dropna()
```